# Vertical Align Bootstrap Radio Button Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to combine `input-group-addon` with `radio` elements. Example code is below.

http://www.bootply.com/1M34c3sy29

But the `radio` *image* is not centered for *Price* `radio` section.

Is it possible to center the image for the *Price* section? Or do you recommend another solution for such kind of presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is adding some styling that will not allow the vertical align to function as you need. The elements are absolutely positioned. I'd try positioning the radio button another way, using the `top` css property:

```css
.input-group { display:inline-block;}

#inlineradio2{ top: 13px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal">
 <fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
      <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option1" type="radio">
      Automatic. Price will be set by the system!</label>
    </div>     
    <div class="radio">
     <label>
    <input id="inlineradio2" name="sampleinlineradio" value="option2" type="radio">
    <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Price</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="price-box" aria-describedby="Price">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
   </label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've also changed the name of the HTML `id` attribute on the radio button in question as [the `id` should be unique](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Thank you very much. How do you calculate 13px please? If user increases font size for her page, 13px may not be reliable. I think my way is not standard and might be buggy. Do you still recommend 13px workaround or another standard solution?

Comment: I came up with 13px by eyeing the center spot. I do not see this being a problem unless you plan on changing the height/padding of the 'input-group-addon' span or the input text box that are to the side of it in a media query or something. If that is the case you can update the top property in the media query as well. If the user updates the zoom the radio button will also increase size and proportions will be the same. You can never fully guarantee your site will appear correctly, as css is rendered on the client side and can be manipulated by the user.